# '...a bag of finger bones...' Does Melisandre have plans for Davos?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

When describing to John Snow how a illusion works (talking about Mance's disguise as the Lord of Bones in the books) Melisandre states that having something from the person who you are being disguised as, such as:

> A dead mans boots or a bag of finger bones (I've paraphrased as I don't have the exact text right now)

helps make the illusion more real.

The bag of finger bones immediately reminded me of Davos, who'd lost his lucky knuckle bones during the attack on King's Landing and his almost drowning.

As Melisandre has met and interacted with Davos, is this a sign that she maybe that the bones, and has some yet unrevealed plan for using them, or him?

Comment: Unfortunately since this isn't covered in either the books or the TV show I'm voting to close this as Primarily Opinion Based as per our future works policy.

Comment: @Edlothiad I wasn't sure if it was covered any further in the books. I've read them all, but upon re-reading them I noticed this line, and started to wonder what's in the next (currently last) book. If there's nothing then I agree with your flag.

Comment: Well my flag merely states that until we get more information, we don't know. Remember a question can always be re-opened when an answer is found!

Comment: Davos specifically showed his fingers to the Iron Bank when visiting with Stannis, and mentioned that this was **punishment** for his earlier smuggling, as decided by Stannis. Davos used this explanation to justify that he thinks Stannis is a righteous and just ruler. Davos did not lose his fingers in the Battle of Blackwater Bay, he lost them around the time where he started working with Stannis.

Comment: @Flater -- in the battle of Blackwater bay, when he fell into the river, his finger bones, kept on a thong around his neck, were gone when he awoke on the island. This **seems** to be important later on, as he is constantly reaching for the pouch around his neck, and recalling that he has 'lost his luck'.

Comment: @djsmiley2k: My mistake, I wasn't aware of the finger bones being kept by Davos up until the Battle of BWB.